# How to use greater than and lower than in xslt

Tags: xslt

I want to use this for logic. my logic is `If the wind speed is >4 and ≤15, then use the graphic`. How can I use xslt for `>4 and ≤15`.

Tried code:

```
<xsl:when test="td[7] > 4 -and- td[7] ">
```

I am using XSLT 2.0

Comment: But the problem is how use ≤ it contain the equal symbol also

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `<` and `>`, use `&lt;` and `&gt;`...

```
<xsl:when test="td[7] &gt; 4 and td[7] &lt;= 15">...</xsl:when>
```

Notice how I put the `=` straight after the `&lt;` to replicate `<=`

---

As per the comment by @TimC, the only one you **have** to escape is the `<` to `&lt;`.

The `>` can be left as is, but my preference is to change both for consistency.

---

As per the comment by @MichaelKay, XPath 2.0 allow you to use just `lt` and `gt`...

```
<xsl:when test="td[7] gt 4 and td[7] lt= 15">...</xsl:when>
```

And he also notes that another way of writing the same thing, but still using `>`...

```
<xsl:when test="15 >= td[7] and td[7] > 4">...</xsl:when>
```

Comment: Note that you don't actually need to escape the greater-than symbol. `td[7] > 4` will work just fine here. It is only `<` that needs to be escaped.

Comment: Fair enough @Tim, I normally do for consistency

Comment: Some people, for readability, prefer to write `test="15 >= td[7] and td[7] > 4"`. In XPath 2.0 you can also use `test="td[7] gt 4 and td[7] le 15"`.